# OpenMP parallel for inside while inside for (or even inside while)

Tags: loops, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, counting

I have an algorithm that is cost expensive. I want to parallelise it by the use of OpenMP.

I have the following algorithm in fortran 95

```
!For a number of iterations
DO iter=1,itermax
   t=tinter
   !We move on the interval of measurement
   nbcoups=0.d0
   DO WHILE(t<tmax-taille)
      nbcoupsdansttplusdt=0.d0
      !Computation of the number of detections during [t,t+dt]
      DO i_c=imin,imax
         nbcoupsdansttplusdt=nbcoupsdansttplusdt+indicatricestrict(t,compt(i_c,iter),t+taille)
      END DO
      nbcoups=nbcoups+nbcoupsdansttplusdt
      t=t+taille
   END DO
   fenetrage(iter)=nbcoups
END DO
```

where indicatricestrict(t,x,t+taille) = 1_{[t,t+taille]}(x).

I think I can use omp_nested, but the pdf I have said to be carefull with performance. Can you explain me and suggest me a solution?

Thank you for any food of though ;)

I tried to run my code with a large number tmax, and the algorithm takes forever. I want to use nested, but since there are for inside while inside for I don't know what to expect.

Comment: 1. "algorithm takes forever" That is only a problem if it takes *longer* on two threads than on one. Does it? And do you get the same result? 2. there is something missing: each iteration starts  `t=tinter` so they all do the same computation.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I think the OP didn't even try OpenMP yet. (edit) And `iter` is used as an index in the inner loop, so the different iterations do not compute the same things.

Comment: At first glance you can simply parallelize the outer loop, I can't see obvious reasons why it wouldn't work. Why not just trying?

Comment: Yes, I did not try OpenMp now. taille is fixed, t is going from tinter to tmax. does it make sense to you @VictorEijkhout?
Yes, I will try that@PierU !